# Find non-descending sequences of list pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

```
list =
  {{"d", 10}, {"a", 10}, {"a", 12}, {"c", 8}, {"z", 6}, 
   {"a", 6}, {"z", 12}, {"d", 15}, {"b", 14}, {"b", 13}};
```

With `Split` the expected result is easy to get,

```
Cases[{_, __}] @ Split[list, #1[[-1]] <= #2[[-1]] &]
```

{{{"d", 10}, {"a", 10}, {"a", 12}}, {{"z", 6}, {"a", 6}, {"z",
12}, {"d", 15}}}

but the shortest solution using sequence-functions I found needs a
detour via `Takelist`

```
p = Length /@ SequenceCases[Last /@ list, x_ /; LessEqual @@ x]
```

{3, 1, 4, 1, 1}

```
Cases[{_, __}] @ TakeList[list, p]
```

{{{"d", 10}, {"a", 10}, {"a", 12}}, {{"z", 7}, {"a", 8}, {"z",
12}, {"d", 15}}}

**My question**

Is there a shorter, more direct way using `SequenceCases`,
`SequenceSplit` or `SequencePosition` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[list, x : {_, __} /; LessEqual @@ x[[All, -1]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using `SequenceCases` and `OrderedQ`:**

```
SequenceCases[list, x_ /; OrderedQ@Map[Last]@x] /. {_} -> Nothing
```

> {{{"d", 10}, {"a", 10}, {"a", 12}}, {{"z", 6}, {"a", 6}, {"z",
> 12}, {"d", 15}}}